# .htaccess looping when redirecting from http to https

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^xyz  xyz.php [PT]    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

First redirect redirects `www.example.com/xyz` to `www.example.com/xyz.php`.

This works fine.

Second one has a problem.
If I type in `example.com`, it creates an infinite loop to:

`https://example.com/example.com/example.com`

If I type in `www.example.com`, it also creates an infinite loop similar to the above.

I want to redirect everything from:

`http://example.com/...`
`https://example.com/...`
to
`https://www.example.com/...`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't have RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80  declared before the redirect.